# З якої причини ЄС хоче, щоб україна перейшла на латиницю, та які складності виникнуть при створенні нової велесовичниці на основі латиниці

Tags: абетка, альтернативні-правописи

Перед питанням, я хочу написати чому я проти переходу на латиницю.
Коротко: виникне багато с проблем.

1. Проблема позначення літер `Я Ю Є Ї` або палатальності приголосних(пом'якшення). Приклад `Niagaru(Нягару)` та `Diaspora(Дяспора)`, і використовувати замість `I` літеру `U/Y` теж не є можливим бо тоді світ буде `Nuarnym(Нярним)`
2. Проблема літер `Х Г Ґ`. Латинське позначення `G` передає букву `Ґ`, а що з `Г`. Позначення `H` в багатьох мовах передає не `[x]` а  `[h]` або `[ɦ]`.
3. Проблема збільшення двознаків, при невикористанні дифтонгів.
4. Проблема літер `W` та `V`. Перша позначає `Ў` а друга `В`.

Ціль переходу: щоб європейці змогли зрозуміти наше письмо. Але це не набагато полегшить людині, незнайомій з українською читати її та розуміти, бо вона незнайома з нею. Тому найкращим виходом я бачу саме зроблення латиниці для назв вулиць і всього іншого. І написання поруч з нашою.

Приклад на Польщі та Чехії. Вони не можуть зрозуміти і прочитати деякі з літер. Для цього потрібно знати ці мови. Інакше нічого не вийде.

Єдиний плюс, так це в кодуванні символів для ЕОТ, і то тільки при НЕ використанні дифтонгів.

Так де ж я помилився, і як вирішити описані проблеми(якщо вони є).

Comment: Перепрошую, а чому Ви раптом вирішили, що ***ЄС*** хоче, щоб ми перейшли на латиницю? Може, хтось у ЄС про це й казав, але я цього ніколи не чув. Я був певен, що то суто наші внутрішні приколи.

Comment: Звідки інформація про те, що ЄС хоче, щоб в Україні запровадили латиницю замість кирилиці?

Comment: Про всьак зазначу, же Бъґария, котра вже је членом ЕС, досье̂ послуговује сја кирилицьоју.

Comment: Що таке *велесивочниця*?

Comment: Здається під *велесовочницію* автор має на увазі абетку велесової книги. Згадується [тут](https://youtu.be/njFa9ICAmq0?t=224).